# My second scan function isn't working, and defaults to pulling the second value from my array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

In my code I have a scan function that gets values for an array from the user. It then goes to ask the user the number of terms they want to sort. This scan function doesn't allow the user to input a number but instead takes the second number from the array.

I have tried changing the names of variables, I have moved the code from two separate functions into the same function. I have tried troubleshooting by placing print statements before and after the scanf, which is how I figured out that the scan variable is assigned the second value of the array (no matter what the user enters in that slot), even though it is initialized to 0.

Enter number of elements to sort -> 2 is my number

The user is supposed to be able to enter code here`r a number between 1 and 9 after the print "Enter the number of elements you wish to sort". Currently the variable num is being assigned the second value in the array and the user doesn't have the opportunity to enter in a number.

Comment: Add getchar() after the scan line so that input buffer will be cleaned.

Comment: Reveiw the need for the 2nd space in `" %d "`.  Taylor123, Why do you have that?

Comment: That was an accident, but doesn't change anything when removed @chux

Comment: I added getchar() and that didn't help either @MuhammedGül

Comment: Post example  text  input used and output seen.  Also post the rest of `getInput(int array[])`.  What is `SIZE`??

Comment: I edited the code to have the rest of the function as well as the input/output example. The user enters the numbers (up to 20, ending with a -1) and it prints out the second value (2 in this case) without having the user enter another number.

Comment: We need a `[mcve].

Comment: @chux the output I posted is copied exactly from my code, that is all that there is. The user enters a set of numbers (1 2 3 4 -1) and the program prints 2 for the value of num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@xing [is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678553/my-second-scan-function-isnt-working-and-defaults-to-pulling-the-second-value?noredirect=1#comment98042450_55678553).

```
//                                                             v  
// for (count = 0; count < SIZE && array[count] != -1; count++);
for (count = 0; count < SIZE && array[count] != -1; count++)
```